# Why condition returns True using regular expressions for finding special characters in the string?

Tags: regex, string, python-3.x, if-statement

I need to validate the variable names:

```
name = ["2w2", " variable", "variable0", "va[riable0", "var_1__Int", "a", "qq-q"]
```

And just names `"variable0", "var_1__Int" and "a"` are correct.

I could Identify most of "wrong" name of variables using `regex`:

```
import re
if re.match("^\d|\W|.*-|[()[]{}]", name):
    print(False)
else:
    print(True)
```

However, I still become `True` result for `va[riable0`. Why is it the case?
I control for all type of parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.match()` checks for a match only at the beginning of the string, while `.search()` checks for a match anywhere in the string.

You can also simplify your regex to this and call `search()` method:

```
^\d|\W
```

That basically checks whether first character is digit or a non-word is anywhere in the input.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4bBfug/1)

[Code Demo](http://ideone.com/07Rx5M)

**Code:**

```
>>> name = ["2w2", " variable", "variable0", "va[riable0", "var_1__Int", "a", "qq-q"]
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'^\d|\W')
>>> for str in name:
...     if pattern.search(str):
...             print(str + ' => False')
...     else:
...             print(str + ' => True')
...
2w2 => False
 variable => False
variable0 => True
va[riable0 => False
var_1__Int => True
a => True
qq-q => False
```

Comment: It is clearly a better solution. Could you say, what was wrong with mine? Why have I got True instead of False even when the condition for False statement was executed?

Comment: `.match()` checks for a match only at the beginning of the string, while `.search()` checks for a match anywhere in the string. Also hyphen or parentheses are non-word characters so just `|W` takes care of them.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression is:

```
"^\d|\W|.*-|[()[]{}]"
```

But `re.match()` matches from the beginning of the string always, so your `^` is unnecessary, but you need a `$` at the end, to make sure the entire input string matches, and not just a prefix.

Comment: Right! I have corrected my expression and now it searches through the whole string: `"\d|\W|.*-|[()[]{}]$"` and the result is `True` instead of `False` again for variable `"va[riable0"`. The output, that regex found, is: `['[', '0']`.